# concordance index in python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, survival-analysis

I'm looking for a python/sklearn/lifelines/whatever implementation of `Harrell's c-index` (concordance index), which is mentioned in [random survival forests](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1645.pdf).

The C-index is calculated using the following steps:

1. Form all possible pairs of cases over the data.
2. Omit those pairs whose shorter survival time is censored. Omit pairs i and j if `Ti=Tj` unless at least one is a death. Let `Permissible` denote the total number of permissible pairs.
3. For each permissible pair where `Ti` and `Tj` are not equal, count 1 if the shorter survival
   time has worse predicted outcome; count 0.5 if predicted outcomes are tied. For each permissible pair, where `Ti=Tj` and both are deaths, count 1 if predicted outcomes are tied; otherwise, count 0.5. For each permissible
   pair where `Ti=Tj`, but not both are deaths, count 1 if the death has
   worse predicted outcome; otherwise, count 0.5. Let Concordance denote
   the sum over all permissible pairs.
4. The C-index, `C`, is defined by `C=Concordance/Permissible`.

Note: `nltk` has a `ConcordanceIndex` method with a different meaning :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LifeLines package now has this implemented [c-index, or concordance-index](http://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#model-selection-in-survival-regression)

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @dhamelse's answer, apologize I don't have enough reputation to comment.

**Lifelines**

```
lifelines.utils.concordance_index(event_times, predicted_scores, event_observed=None)
```

The expected `predicted_scores` are predicted survival times. If the predicted scores are risks/hazards, multiply by -1 as shown in the doc code example ([explained by the author](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352183/use-median-survival-time-to-calculate-cph-c-statistic/352435#352435)).

Note that `event_observed` is optional. Though if not provided, with right censoring, the computed c index would be inflated.

**Sksurv**

```
sksurv.metrics.concordance_index_censored(event_indicator, event_time, estimate, tied_tol=1e-08)
```

The expected `estimate` is risk/hazard. Be careful when using for models such as accelerated failure time AFT model, in which case, multiply the estimated survival time by -1 to get the normal interpretation.

Supposedly, based on the source code below it should return the correct c index, but I got the incorrect one when fitting an AFT model.

```
risk_score = self.predict(X)
        if not getattr(self, "_predict_risk_score", True):
            risk_score *= -1  # convert prediction on time scale to risk scale

result = concordance_index_censored(y[name_event], y[name_time], risk_score)
```

**Another Note**

Instead of multiplying the predicted scores by -1, one can also use 1 - c index to get the correct value after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

LifeLine package could implement concordance index.

`pip install lifelines`

or

`conda install -c conda-forge lifelines`

Example:

```
from lifelines.utils import concordance_index
cph = CoxPHFitter().fit(df, 'T', 'E')
concordance_index(df['T'], -cph.predict_partial_hazard(df), df['E'])
```

Comment: why is there a '-' before the predicted hazards [cph.predict_partial_hazard(df)]?

Answer (score 0):

Lifelines is a great tool for this and all Survival Analysis in Python. I cant comment yet, but it is important to note that Lifelines `concordance_index()` only matches scikit-survival's `concordance_index_censored()` if the "predictions" argument is multiplied by (-1).

This just boils down to a different interpretation of the expected predictions (or "risk scores") between the two packages.